# Prove $ A = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x+y \neq 4 \} $ is an open set

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-explanation

**Problem**: Prove $ A = \{  (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x+y \neq 4 \} $ is an open set

**Proof**:
Let $ (x,y) \in A $. We'll choose $ r = \frac{|x+y-4|}{2} $ and if $ (u,v) \in B( (x,y) ,r ) $ then
$ | u-x| \leq \sqrt{| u-x |^2 + |v-y|^2} < r $
$ | v-y| \leq \sqrt{| u-x |^2 + |v-y|^2} < r  $

$ | u+v - (x+y) | \leq | u-x | + | v - y | < 2r  $
Hence,  $ | u + v -4  | = | ( u-x+v-y) + ( x+y-4) | \geq | | u-x+v-y | - |x+y-4| | = | |u-x+v-y| - 2r | = | 2r - |u+v-(x+y)| |   > 0  $

In particular we have that $ u+v \neq 4 $ hence $ (u,v) \in A$ and we proved that $ B( (x,y),r) \subseteq A $ hence $ A $ is open.

**Question**: The proof above is from lecture notes. I didn't understand how they knew the metric/distance function is the Euclidian metric in 2D, it is not given what the distance function is in the metric space $ \langle A, d  \rangle $ so as far as that's the main concern, the distance function could be anything ( over $ A $, of course ).
If I were to prove on my own, I'd write the line " Let $ (x,y) \in A $. We'll choose $ r = \frac{|x+y-4|}{2} $ and if $ (u,v) \in B( (x,y) ,r ) $ then $ d( (u,v),(x,y) ) < r  $ " and I wouldn't know how to proceed since I don't know what $ d $ is.
So to **sum up**, my question is - how I should've inferred that the distance function is the Euclidian distance in 2D? ( since no information about the distance function is given )

Comment: It has to be written somewhere. The statement is meaningless without that information.

Comment: In general, one could say, if no particular distance function is given, the distance function has to be "obvious" from context. On the Euclidean spaces $\mathbf R^n$, the "natural" choice is the Euclidean distance.

Comment: It must have been a given.  Perhaps it was a poorly organized class and they had forgotten to make the statement "The definition of the euclidean metric is the square root of the sum of the squares of the differences of components" but the must define the metric before they can ask the question.

Comment: I thought so myself, I've seen similar exercises without the distance function being explicitly mentioned. I think in most cases if it is not written, one assumes the Euclidian distance function ( when talking about  subspaces of $  \mathbb{R}^n $ )

Comment: It'd be interesting to try to define a metric where the set is not open (or to prove none can exist).

Comment: @fleablood I've just started studying about this material. Is the set's openness depend on the metric? can there be sets which are open for one metric but not open for another?

Comment: Absolutely!  Take the discreet metric.   $d(x,y) =\begin{cases} 0 &x=y\\1&x\ne y\end{cases}$.  In that case *every* set is both open and closed.  (Proof that all sets are open:  Let $S$ be a non-empty set.  Let $x\in S$.  Then $B_{\frac 12}(x)=\{y|d(x,y)< \frac 12\}=\{y|(\begin{cases} 0 &x=y\\1&x\ne y\end{cases}) < \frac 12\}=\{y|y=x\} = \{x\}\subset S$. So $S$ is open [the empty set is vaccuously open])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you talk about $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a metric space you implicitly take the standard Euclidean distance

$$d:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R},$$
$$(x,y)\mapsto\sqrt{\sum_{1\leq j \leq n}(x_j-y_j)^2},$$

so if no metric is explicitly stated, this can very safely be assumed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
A & = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x + y \neq 4\}\\\\
& = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x + y < 4\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x + y > 4\}\\\\
& = f^{-1}(-\infty,4) \cup f^{-1}(4,+\infty)
\end{align*}

where $f:(\mathbb{R}^{2},\|\cdot\|_{2})\to(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ is given by $f(x,y) = x + y$.

Since $f$ is continuous (it is a polynomial) and the set $(-\infty,4)$ as well as the set $(4,+\infty)$ are open, their pre-image are open as well. Consequently, their union is also open, just as desired.

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: "Since f is continuous (it is a polynomial) "  If you do not know what the metric is, how would you know that polynomials are continuous?

Comment: @fleablood It is a good point. But I assume the metric to be the Euclidean one.

Comment: But that was the *entire* thrust of the OPs question:  Why is it assumed that the metric is the Euclidean one.  (To which I don't think there can be any answer but "It seems they just did").

Comment: @fleablood maybe I have not paid enough attention to the body of the question.